# Did Damian Lewis appear in Season 6?

Tags: character, homeland

In *Homeland* season 3 Damian Lewis' character, Nicholas Brody, died. However, Damian Lewis was still present in show one way or another.

- In season 4, We see Damian Lewis

> portraying Nicholas Brody in a hallucination by Carrie.

- In season 5, We see Damian Lewis in

> portraying Nicholas Brody in a picture.

- He even appeared in Season 7

> portraying Nicholas Brody live albeit in a flashback.

- He even appeared in Season 8

> through the tape he made in season 1. This was played at the start of the finale.

Did he appear in Season 6?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't back this up with facts ATM (and I'm not planning on rewatching season 6 any time soon, I didn't really like it), but IIRC, he didn't, and wasn't even mentioned *by name* (only indirectly).

Comment: @Walt Thanks but the name 'Nicholas Brody' was explicitly stated by a character in Season 6 right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## No, he wasn't in Season 6.

(according to IMDB)

I did a search of the cast for each of the Season 6 episodes (using IMDB). I made sure to show the "full cast" before searching. Damian Lewis doesn't show up in any of them.

Oddly, he doesn't appear in the cast for Season 5 or 7 either. Perhaps those were replays of previous scenes as opposed to newly filmed scenes? He is credited in Season 4 episode 7 ("Redux").